# stacked bar graph with ggplot2 library in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

```
DMU Name    trip    rate    time    sline   distan  wait    gate
Sadang      0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
Jamsil      0.00    0.10    0.15    0.31    0.04    0.29    0.20 
Silim       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
Guro        0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
Suwon       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
Suyu        0.06    0.26    0.21    0.23    0.12    0.34    0.30
```

I have a data as above, and I want to plot a stacked bar graph.

I tried to do it this way:

```
##graph
gr <- read.csv("graph.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",")

library(tidyr)
#convert into long format
df2<-gather(gr, key=Input,  value, -DMU.Name)

 library(ggplot2)


 ggplot(df2, aes(DMU.Name)) +geom_bar(aes(weight= value, fill = Input))+
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60, hjust=1)) +
 scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Sadang","Jamsil","Silim","Guro Digital Complex",
 "Suwon","Sindorim","Suyu","Gangnam","Seoul Nat'l Univ.",
 "Yangjae","Bucheon","Gangbyeon","Seoul","Hongik Univ.","Bupyeong",
 "Yeongdeungpo","Sinchon","Samsung","Gasan Digital Complex","Konkuk University", 
 "Univ. of Education","Express Bus Terminal", "Seolleung", "Apgujeong","Gwanghwamun",
 "Hyehwa","Euljiro 1(il)-ga", "Yeonsinnae","Jonggak","Yeoksam","Chungmuro","Myeong-dong")) +
   scale_fill_discrete(limits = c ("trip","rate","time","sline","distan","wait","gate","lines","stops","allocation"))
```

However, I want to change the bar color set.

How do I try to??

Thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhfXP.gif)

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example as well as a more detailed description of your problem? Specifically, why would you expect anything to be stacked in the code example you provide?

Comment: For a barplot you need to specify either a y variable and `stat = "identity"`, or `stat = "count"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick solution:

```
df<-read.table(header = TRUE, text=
"DMUName    trip    rate    time    sline   distan  wait    gate
Sadang      0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
Jamsil      0.00    0.10    0.15    0.31    0.04    0.29    0.20 
Silim       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
Guro        0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
Suwon       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
Suyu        0.06    0.26    0.21    0.23    0.12    0.34    0.30")

library(tidyr)
#convert into long format
df2<-gather(df, key=Name,  value, -DMUName)

library(ggplot2)
#plot
g<-ggplot(df2, aes(DMUName)) +geom_bar(aes(weight= value, fill =Name))
print(g)
```